# PRIMARY KEY for duplicate values only in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I developed a unique index by combining few possible fields of a particular table, again I ended up with duplicate values in that unique index.

So I wish to know, Is it possible to create "ID PRIMARY KEY" only for those duplicate values?
So that I'll combine that with my unique index to escape from the duplicates (unique_index||'_'||id)

**TABLE**

| unique_index | id | final_uniqe |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rose | null | rose |
| jasmine | 1 | jasmine_1 |
| jasmine | 2 | jasmine_2 |
| sunflower | 1 | sunflower_1 |
| sunflower | 2 | sunflower_2 |
| sunflower | 3 | sunflower_3 |
| lily | null | lily |

Comment: knowing that a primary key cannot contain columns with null values
If you don't want duplicate rows, why not use in the query SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ... FROM table_name;

Comment: Rather than finding a workaround, it may behoove  you to validate that you do not already have data corruption.  Are the 3 (not so) 'unique_index' column values for *sunflower* really 3 different things, or the result or poor data integrity and represent just 1 thing  to the business. Your proposal will get you around the DB requirements but break the business rule - **which is far more important**. If they actually are 3 different things to the business then you can create a unique constraint on the columns together `constraint x unique( unique_index, id)` and have no need for a new column.

Answer (score 0):

The smart thing to do in this case is to add an autogenerated `bigint` column and use only that as a primary key.

Primary keys that consist of many columns are cumbersome; for example, each table that has a foreign key constraint to your table must contain all primary key columns. Also, a primary key cannot contain columns that can hold NULL values.